# Передать параметр в php

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
 var str = encodeURI('Сообщение');
 var phpAdress = "test.php";
 window.location.href = phpAdress+'?str';
</script>
```

test.php

```
 <?php
     print $_GET[str];
 ?>
```

Пытаюсь передать параметр переменной в php файл, подскажите, что мне нужно  исправить чтобы на `test.php` вывелось значение переменной `str`.
Опирался на этот [пример](http://htmlhook.ru/vzaimodejstvie-php-i-javascript.html)

Comment: Правильней использовать `$_GET["str"]`. Т.е. индекс массива должен быть строкой. В примере все и так сработает, но с выдачей предупреждения об неопределенной константе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Иcправить строку формирования URL на следующую

```
window.location.href = phpAdress + '?str=' + str;
```

Параметры передаются в виде `имя_параметра=значение_параметра` В вашем же примере вы передаете имя параметра, без значения.

И в качестве совета на будущее - для отладки таких ситуаций лучше в PHP делать дамп всего массива **$_GET**. Например, вот так

```
print_r($_GET);
```